# Spinner not a view that can be bounds(sp) by this SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, cursor, spinner

I'm trying to adapt my query to my spinner object with some trouble, I get the error listed as the title. Here is the code portion where it crashes:

```
        Spinner classDropDown = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.classDropDown);
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.classDropDown };
        String[] classFields = new String[] { "className" };
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, cursor, classFields, to);
        cursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.id.classDropDown);
        classDropDown.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

I had a problem where the cursor wasn't being filled but fixed that now. Can someone give me help on debugging this issue?

**Edit:** I think my problem is the "to" field. What should this be?

**Edit 2:** Also, here is the XML for the spinner object:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/classDropDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Edit 3:** I've fixed the above to reflect fixing the code. This fixes this particular problem. I'm not getting the error, but I also have nothing displayed in the spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To is a list of resource ids that you want to put your data into, such as R.id.textview1, and they meed to be contained in the layout you specify in the adapter.  The number of elements should also match the number of elements in your from array ( you called it classfields).

So, you have two pieces of data and only specified one target resource id.  Either remove one of the fields in your classfields array or add a widget to your layout and call.it in your to array and it should work.

Comment: Ok, so the cursor has to return the same number of fields that are in the "from" and "to" fields as well I'm guessing? Also, what do you mean by proper resource id? Lastly, if I'm only filling the spinner, it's not a problem that I use it for the "to" field is it? Or do I need some extra TextField for it?

Comment: Nope, you can return whatever extras you want in the cursor.  It must have an _id column, but you don't have to display it, its just used by the framework.  All that must match is the number if datafields.in the from and the number of resource ids.in the to ( and of course.the datadields in the from need.to be in your cursor).